# What should roasted pistachio oil smell like?

Tags: oil, nuts, spoilage

I've had a bottle of roasted pistachio oil sitting in my refrigerator for about two years now, that someone gifted me.  Every day I open the refrigerator and it *stares* at me.  Today I decided that enough was enough, and I'd try and finally get it out of my life by substituting it in a biscotti recipe.

It's over a year past the expiration date, but I've been storing it in the fridge ever since I got it.  Now, I'm very familiar with what rancid *neutral* oils smell like, and even rancid olive oil.  But I'm not sure how to detect whether a *roasted nut oil* has gone rancid.  It has a very strong smell, but when I taste it, I don't notice any bitterness.

What should it smell like, if it is in fact still fresh?

Answer (score 2):

You are the best judge here. and you have stated that it doesn't smell bad.  Go ahead and use it - it will be ok.  The fact that it is a 'roasted' nut oil is no different from it being an 'unroasted' one.